# cuadrado mágico

Tags: java

Estoy haciendo un cuadrado mágico y hasta ahora he hecho esto, pero cuando se crea el array me da un error [image: error que me sale en la ejecución del programa]

Esto es lo que he hecho:

```
   boolean Filas = false, Columnas = false;
    Scanner teclado = new Scanner(System.in);
    int dato1 = 0;
    int dato2 = 0;
    int sumaColumna = 0;
    int sumaFila = 0;
    int cuadradoMagico = 0;
    int numero = cuadradoMagico;
    int c = 0; //constante "magica"

    System.out.println("Introduce números y el programa determinará si es un cuadrado magico ó no.   ");
    cuadradoMagico = teclado.nextInt();

    int[][] cuadro = new int[cuadradoMagico][cuadradoMagico];

    for (int j = 0; j < cuadradoMagico; j++) {
        for (int i = 0; i < cuadradoMagico; i++) {
            System.out.println("valor añadido correctamente en el array, en la posición : " + j + "," + i);
            cuadro[j][i] = Integer.parseInt(teclado.next());
        }
    }
    for (int j = 0; j < cuadradoMagico; j++) {
        for (int i = 0; i < cuadradoMagico; i++) {
            System.out.print(cuadro[j][i] + " ");

        }
        System.out.println();

    }
    for (int j = 0; j < cuadradoMagico; j++) {

        dato1 = dato1 + cuadro[j][j];
        dato2 = dato2 + cuadro[(numero - 1) - j][(numero - 1) - j];
    }

    if (dato1 == c && dato2 == c) {
        Filas = true;
    } else {
        Filas = false;
    }

    for (int j = 3; j < numero; j++) {
        for (int i = 0; i < numero; i++) {
            sumaColumna = sumaColumna + cuadro[j][i];
            sumaFila = sumaFila + cuadro[i][j];
        }
        if (sumaColumna != c && sumaFila != c) {
            Columnas = false;

        } else {
            sumaColumna = 0;
            sumaFila = 0;
        }
    }
    Columnas = true;

    if (Columnas == true && Filas == true) {
        System.out.println(" Es un cuadrado mágico");
    } else {
        System.out.println(" No es un cuadrado magico");
    }

}
```

}

No se dónde tengo el error, pero siempre me sale el error "**ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException**"

Comment: ¿podrías poner la traza del error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
int cuadradoMagico = 0;
int numero = cuadradoMagico;
cuadradoMagico = teclado.nextInt();
```

¿Cuánto vale `numero`? 0.

Cualquier operación posterior en la que uses `numero` va a dar un resultado extraño porque no vale lo que tu esperas. Como por ejemplo:

```
for (int j = 0; j < cuadradoMagico; j++) {
    dato1 = dato1 + cuadro[j][j];
    dato2 = dato2 + cuadro[(numero - 1) - j][(numero - 1) - j]; // <<--- AQUI!!!
}
```

La asignación de `numero` debe hacerse **después** de asignar el valor a `cuadradoMagico`:

```
cuadradoMagico = teclado.nextInt();
int numero = cuadradoMagico;
```

Por otro lado, viendo el uso que haces de `cuadradoMagico` y `numero` parece que la variable `numero` sobra ya que siempre va a tener el mismo valor que `cuadradoMagico`. Sustituye `numero` por `cuadradoMagico` y conseguirás tener un código un poco más legible y con menos variables.

Comment: Tienes razón, ahora que he encontrado el error voy a optimizar el programa para no utilizar tantas variables. Muchas gracias por tu respuesta

Answer (score 2):

El problema que tienes es que igualas numero a cuadrado mágico antes de cambiarle el valor a cuadrado mágico.

```
int cuadradoMagico = 0;
int numero = cuadradoMagico;
```

por lo tanto la variable número es igual a 0.

Posteriormente, como no vuelves a igualar la variable `numero` a `cuadradoMagico` esta va a seguir valiendo 0 durante toda la ejecución del programa. Por tanto, cuando hagas la siguente ejecución:

```
dato2 = dato2 + cuadro[(numero - 1) - j][(numero - 1) - j];
```

Va a intentar acceder a la posición `numero - 1` del array, es decir, a la posición -1 del array, lo cual es imposible.

Como puedes observar el error te indica este mismo error:

> java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: **-1**

Simplemente cuando obtengas el valor de `cuadradoMagico` tendrás que volver a asignar de nuevo el valor a la variable `numero`:

```
cuadradoMagico = teclado.nextInt();
numero = cuadradoMagico;
```

Comment: Gracias por contestar, ya he podido solucionar el problema

Comment: @bpico De nada! Me alegro que te haya servido de utilidad :). Simplemente como consejo para la siguiente vez: normalmente el error suele ser bastante identificativo con lo que te pasa. Por ejemplo, `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` da a entender que te has salido del límite del array (con los índices).

Comment: Gracias por contestar siempre que publico una pregunta :) , soy una novata en Java y en cualquier error me ofusco y no veo mas xD

Comment: @bpico No hay nada que agradecer, es un placer :). No te preocupes, a todos nos ha pasado al principio (también a mí) pero ahora es mi lenguaje favorito. Todo con paciencia al final sale ^^

Answer (score 1):

El error lo estará dando aquí:

```
for (int j = 0; j < cuadradoMagico; j++) {

    dato1 = dato1 + cuadro[j][j];
    dato2 = dato2 + cuadro[(numero - 1) - j][(numero - 1) - j]; //Aqui da el ERROR
}
```

ya que la variable `numero` la inicializas al principio igualándola a la variable `cuadradoMagico` que vale 0

```
int cuadradoMagico = 0;
int numero = cuadradoMagico;
```

por lo que cuando recoges por teclado el valor de cuadradoMagico

```
cuadradoMagico = teclado.nextInt();
```

deberías inicializar la variable `numero` también:

```
numero = cuadradoMagico;
```

Comment: Gracias, he conseguido solucionar el error.

Comment: @bpico Me alegro de que te haya servido de ayuda. Saludos!